# Button click in gridview not firing when inside update panel

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, gridview

```
<asp:Timer ID="timer1" runat="server" Interval="1000" OnTick="Timer1_Tick" />
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" id="pnlUpdate">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="timer1" eventname="Tick"/>
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="table table-hover table-condensed" 
            GridLines="None" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="20"
            OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="50%" DataField="Story" HeaderText="Story"/>
            <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="15%" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" DataField="AssignedTo" HeaderText="Assigned To"/>
            <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="15%" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" DataField="Status" HeaderText="Status"/>
            <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="15%" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" DataField="Started" HeaderText="Started"/>
            <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="5%" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" DataField="Updated" HeaderText="Updated"/>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="Buttonid" runat="server" CommandName="ViewItem" Text="View"  BorderStyle="None" BackColor="White" 
                        OnClick="Button_click_event"></asp:Button>   
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
        <RowStyle CssClass="cursor-pointer" />
        </asp:GridView>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

`Button_click_event` won't fire when I have update panel, but it works when it is not in the update panel.

Answer (score 0):

your update panel look like

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upWall" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="true" UpdateMode="conditional">
 <ContentTemplate>
     ....
 </ContentTemplate>
<Triggers>
 <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Buttonid" EventName="Click"/>
</Triggers>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `UpdateMode="Conditional"` and `ChildrenAsTriggers="False"` to the UpdatePanel..

```
 <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="GridView1" />
        </Triggers>
```

Also remove the EventName attribute for your trigger and try again..

Answer (score 0):

Remove the attribute of button click   CommandName="ViewItem" 
and then try , if not work also add Property of button UseSubmitBehaviour=true

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this in various ways. One way is on rowdatabound in the code behind adding a control that can handle an onclick event, for example a div, and  then add a postback handler to your clickable control:

```
HtmlGenericControl div = (HtmlGenericControl)e.Row.FindControl("Buttonid");
div.Attributes.Add("onclick", Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(GridView1, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex.ToString()));
```

Alternatively, I implemented another workaround that works for me:

place a button outside your gridview, but inside the Updatepanel. Also, add a hiddencontrol, where you are going to store the rowindex clicked. Then Add to your template field a 'clickable div' (in which you can put a label for your text), that calls a javascript. Something like this (you can add a display none style to hide the button).:

```html
  <asp:Button id="Buttonid" runat="server" OnClick="Button_click_event" />
  <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnRowClicked" runat="server" Value="" />
    
  <itemtemplate>
    <div onclick="javascript:rowClicked('<%= Buttonid.ClientID %>','<%= hdnRowClicked.ClientID %>', this);">
      <asp:Label ID="lblImgDetail" runat="server" Text="+"></asp:Label>    
    </div>
  </itemtemplate>
```

Then within the javascript function, set the rowindex and call the button to do the postback:

```js
    function rowClicked(btnId, hdnRowSelected, lnk) {
        var rowIndex = lnk.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex - 1;

        $('#' + hdnRowSelected).val(rowIndex);
        $('#' + btnId).click();
    }
```